# How to structure this sql query to create the following new table?

Tags: mysql

Assume I have the following tables:

tableA

```
a_name | age | country
Jordan | 5 | Germany
Molly | 6 | Spain
Paris | 7 | France
```

tableB

```
b_name | age | country
Kyle | 5 | Germany
Bob | 6 | Spain
Bob | 7 | Spain
Stephen | 7 | France
Kyle | 9 | France
Mario | 2 | Mexico
```

I want to make it such that I can produce a tableC that contains:

```
id (auto increment primary key) | age | country | country_marker
1 | 5 | Germany | 1
2 | 6 | Spain | 2
3 | 7 | France | 3
4 | 7 | Spain | 2
5 | 8 | France | 3
6 | 9 | France | 3
7 | 2 | Mexico | 4
```

For the new table:

- takes any unique "age, country" pair only and putting them into tableC with "country_marker" automatically assigning incrementing unique numbers based on distinct "country"

Note there is no countries table, as the "country" in tableC is just based on whatever countries are in tableA, and tableB and country_marker is just a system generated identifier to indicate the unique countries in the table. Output tableC "id and country marker" ordering does not matter as long as it meets the bullet above.

I have painfully tried to produce this using MySQL cursors and want to know if its possible/what is some SQL query or set of queries I could use that would make this faster than using cursors.

Comment: Is the country_marker column a primary key of country table?

Comment: Assume that there is no country table. The only reason it placed a number for country marker (that is sort of auto incrementing) based on the data that is selected from tableA and tableB. Using cursors, I would iterate through tableA and tableB, inserting each unique age,country pair into a new table and country_marker would be incremented as it encounters a unique country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd approach this by first creating table C in something like phpmyadmin. Then I'd write a query to pull the information from tables A and B that I want to put into C. Then, within phpmyadmin, I'd export the results of the query to a .sql file on my local machine. I'd open the .sql file to make the necessary modifications to the INSERT statements so that I can import the data in the .sql file to table C.

This isn't exactly the most efficient way, but it seems like the least technical way that would definitely work.